# Can anyone suggest me a book to study GMM estimator?

Tags: references, econometrics, generalized-moments

I need to learn GMM (Generalized Method of Moments) estimator to replicate a paper for my Research Workshop class. I have a very limited background in Econometrics and Statistics. Where should I exactly start to study from?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it deals with references and not a substantive question.

Comment: @MichaelChernick Then, where and how should I ask this question?

Comment: @MichaelChernik So what is the purpose of the references tag? Automatically flag questions for closing?

Comment: I think this is on-topic (else why the references tag?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend Hayashi, Econometrics, which develops many estimation techniques from a method-of-moments perspective, highlighting that and how estimators like OLS, IV, 2SLS, 3SLS, SUR and others can be seen as special cases of GMM.